# Taking Multiple User inputs in R

Tags: r

I am creating a program that tracks tools around a warehouse in R. Here is what I have so far:

```
tool <- readline(prompt='Enter a Barcode: ')
if (! tool %in% df$Barcode.Number) {
message("Barcodes not found.")
} else {
initials <- readline(prompt='Enter your Initials: ')
job <- readline(prompt='Enter job number: ')
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))
message("Good to Go!")
df[df$Barcode.Number == tool, "DATE"]  = as.character(Sys.Date())
df[df$Barcode.Number == tool, 'Initial'] = initials
df[df$Barcode.Number == tool, 'Job.Number'] = job
df1 <- df %>% filter(df$Barcode.Number == tool) %>% 
select(Type.Equipment, Location)
print(df1)
df[df$Barcode.Number == tool, "Usage"] = df[df$Barcode.Number == 
tool, "Usage"] + 0.5
df$Status <- ifelse((df$Usage %% 1) , 'Out', 'In')
}
```

Along with some sample Data:

```
Barcode.Number    Type.Equipment Manufacture Times.Used Initials  Job 
    4041        Flashlight    Surefire          1    GP        0
    4680           Capstan       Honda          1    GP        0
    4682 Deep Cut Band Saw   Milwaukee          1    GP        0
```

As you can see, it takes a tool argument, along with an initial and work number input, and updates the columns Date, Job Number, Times.Used, and Initial, based on the inputs from the user. I am having trouble though with inputting multiple values in for variable tool. It currently can only take one number at a time, and thats not necessarily practical for someone looking to check out multiple different items under the same initials and job. This question could be simple but how can I accept multiple different input numbers for tool, and have it still be able to update the data frame for both tools at the the same time. I have tried the following:

```
tool <- readline(prompt='Enter the Barcodes: ')
tools <-scan(text=tool,quiet=TRUE,sep=",")
```

This will save the tools that I have entered as different numbers, but it wont update the frame for the numbers that it saves. I am new to R so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly use: `<-` if you want store to variable not `<=`.

`<=` is a logical operator which checks lesser than or equal to another values or not.

But anyway Your question is vague. But if you want to seprate values with comma you can you `read.table` with `sep=","`:

```
number <- readline(prompt='Enter a Number: ')
values = read.table(text = number,sep=",")
```

So `values` will be a data frame with your values.
In your example desired output you even not need to do that just use this:

```
number <- readline(prompt='Enter a Number: ')
print(paste("Your numbers are",number), quote=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, from here, just as a user, how can one input multiple statements into one line of code? If my input says "Enter a number", and I enter 45, 65, 72, it accepts that number as being "45, 65, 72" rather than "45", 
"65", and "72". How would you suggest I fix this? Thanks again.

Comment: two last lines of my answer is exactly same as your will. @GregPedersen

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scan` to obtain the values you need. Then `cat` to print them out

```
number <- readline(prompt='Enter a Number: ')
cat("Your Numbers are:",scan(text=number,quiet=TRUE,sep=","))
```

With this in mind, you can put the two in a function format:

```
getnumbers = function(){
  number <- readline(prompt='Enter the Numbers: ')
  numbers <-scan(text=number,quiet=TRUE,sep=",")
  cat("Your Numbers are:",numbers)
  invisible(numbers)
 }
getnumbers()
Enter the Numbers: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,13,43
Your Numbers are: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 13 43
```

or if you want to save the numbers, you can do:

```
saved =getnumbers()
Enter the Numbers: 1,2,3,4
Your Numbers are: 1 2 3 4
saved
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I guess my question more so aligns with, how as a user can someone input multiple values into an input statement. For example, if I input "64, 53, 72" into my inpout value above, it will accept that as "64, 53, 72", rather than "64", "53", and "72", How can I get around this problem? Is there a different way it could be input by the user, or do I need to change the input statement to allow for this? Thanks again.